# DDS IDL | Creating a network alias name separate from a structure name

Tags: data-distribution-service

I've had a constraint imposed on me that my C structure names can't be published via DDS and that I instead have to use a different set of names and then *somehow* associate the two.  It begs the question why not just change my C structure to match the actual DDS names but it is impractical since the names have to be configurable at run time.

Discarding the run-time constraint, I am wondering if there is an IDL keyword that I can use to create an alias between my structures and the desired DDS published names.  There is an "alias" keyword but it is for data types.

I did a lot of google searching and had a hard time finding a definition for IDL keywords. The OMG document doesn't provide any insight to indicate this is possible (perhaps it's not).

Comment: Looks like someone else had a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150398/opendds-create-multiple-topics-from-single-idl-structure?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDS, data types are registered with the middleware via a 'register_type()' operation.  This operation includes a parameter to specify the 'name' to associate with the registered type.  This name is not required to match the name of the IDL type.  [If this name is not specified, then the middleware will use the IDL type name.]

Comment: In DDS you need to register a type only if it is used by a DDS Topic.  DDS supports either 'structure' or 'union' types for this purpose.  If a structure has members [elements?] that are also structure types, you do not need to register these 'internal' types, so the name of 'internal' struct types are essentially irrelevant.